After upgrading Docker Desktop to 4.37.1 not able to download Azurite
I had a docker image with a container Azurite from Microsoft Azure.
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite

My machine is Windows 11, and Docker Desktop for windows configured to work with Linux containers, and working with WSL2.
I have been using the containers for long times with many versions of desktop, and I update desktop versions regularly, so my last working version is either 4.36, or 4.35
After upgrade to 4.37.1 I cannot start azurite.
And I cannot see azurite image on my machine.
I have other many images and containers, and they all working except for Azurite docker.
I tried to download (pull) the image using:
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite

but I am getting this error
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from azure-storage/azurite
failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: Get "https://westus2.data.mcr.microsoft.com/01031d61e1024861afee5d512651eb9f-h36fskt2ei//docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/7f/7fd07ddae1b8e6992555b78eaf13184000ca4c48e69b90919640c6a742c78ee8/data?se=2024-12-20T23%3A21%3A47Z&sig=74qL8qkc46y3JCktCMiJxsfAfcFQnRWSFceZ9YnJL5c%3D&sp=r&spr=https&sr=b&sv=2018-03-28&regid=01031d61e1024861afee5d512651eb9f": EOF

I uninstalled the 4.37 version, and installed docker desktop 4.35, but wihout success and the same problem.
I tried docker pull, docker run, with different version tags, and all the same error
My Docker version is 27.4.0, build bde2b89 (I think this coming with Desktop)

I have try with the Docker Desktop 4.37.1 (178610).
And with your command i have this result :
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from azure-storage/azurite
1207c741d8c9: Pull complete
854bbbc098b2: Pull complete
d30ccb81ed57: Pull complete
74a11634af6c: Pull complete
54206864b362: Pull complete
50a691c5108d: Pull complete
c1a537154c77: Pull complete
0eba5b1d04af: Pull complete
8138bbd44987: Pull complete
453690f47a16: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:2628ee10a72833cc344b9d194cd8b245543892b307d16cf26a2cf55a15b816af
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite:latest
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite:latest

What's next:
    View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite

What is your version of docker ? And, your image container have many vulnerabilities, i don't recommand you to use it. Perhaps, an issue with your DNS ?

docker version 27.4.0. I updated my question to add the version

I know it is problem on my machine, and I didn't doubt it is related to docker or Microsoft image. But I am tring to find how to fix it.

Did you setup Docker on a Linux or Windows container? I tried your command with the Windows container setup and it doesn't work, but with the Linux container setup it works fine!

it is Linux with WSL2

Can you try to download directly the image with the url ? And, launch docker as a root user ?
